# How to 'hide' metaClass property in a Groovy class

Tags: reflection, groovy, metaclass

I am creating some simple groovy classes, e.g.

```
class Person {
    int age
    String name
}
```

that are being used in a Java method that relies on reflection to pull out the object properties, e.g. age and name.   The problem is that metaClass is also showing up as a property.  Updating the Java method to ignore this property is not an option.  I've tried setting the metaClass property to null but that didn't work.

Comment: There will be other members added by the compiler in other contexts (like the internal outer reference in an inner class).  Maybe you can update the reflection code to reflect only package/protected/public properties?

Comment: did you find a way to hide metaClass?

Comment: Nope, I just worked around it.

Comment: Don't create them in groovy, seems like they are just POJO's.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using these classes from Java and Groovy why not just create the POJO's in Java and not Groovy. 
I know this doesn't answer your question but it would be nice to know why the decision to use Groovy for the POJOs

Answer (score 0):

MetaClass gets injected for a Groovy class during the creation. IMHO I don't think you can set it to Null. The setMetaClass method which you called only sets any custom metaclass you may have set on your class to Null and not the one which gets injected during construction.